# Spring webflux doesn't populate custom object from path variables with @ModelAttribute

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying to adapt an application that works well with Spring MVC but that has a different behavior with Spring WebFlux

Here's my code with Spring Boot 5 - Spring MVC :

The controller :

```
@RestController
public class MyRestController {

    @GetMapping("/test/{id}/{label}")
    public ResponseEntity<Payload> test(@ModelAttribute Payload payload) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(payload,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

The Payload object :

```
public class Payload {

    @NotNull
    private int id;

    private String label;

    public Payload() {}

    public String getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

    public void setLabel(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

My pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I don't have written any custom converter, Spring populate my payload object automatically, everything is fine.

When I call :

```
http://localhost:8080/test/25/helloWorld
```

Response is

```
{"id":25,"label":"helloWorld"}
```

Then, I only change my pom.xml, switching from web to webflux :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And my Payload Object isn't populated anymore.

When I call :

```
http://localhost:8080/test/25/helloWorld
```

Response is

```
{"id":0,"label":null}
```

I know I could write a converter and register it with @ControllerAdvice, but I can't imagine that there isn't an automated solution to make it works again as it has always worked with Spring Web.

Does anyone already encountered the same problem as me ?

Thanks,

Julien

Answer (score 3):

The [Spring WebFlux reference documentation about `@ModelAttribute`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-modelattrib-method-args) does not mention URI path variables, unlike [the same section in the reference documentation for Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-method-args):

> The Pet instance above is resolved as follows:
>
> - From the model if already added by using Model.
> - From the HTTP session by using `@SessionAttributes`.
> - From a URI path variable passed through a Converter (see the next
>     example).
> - From the invocation of a default constructor.
> - From the invocation of a “primary constructor” with arguments that
>     match to Servlet request parameters. Argument names are determined
>     through JavaBeans `@ConstructorProperties` or through runtime-retained
>     parameter names in the bytecode.

At this point this is the expected behavior and there might be good reasons or limitations behind that choice. [Feel free to open an enhancement request in Spring Framework for that](https://jira.spring.io).

Comment: Thanks Brian, I'll do that !